# How to Access Outer Test Instance/Parameter in a Nested Junit 5 Test

Tags: java, junit, junit5

```
interface MyInterface {}

static class ImplA implements MyInterface {}

static class ImplB implements MyInterface {}

class OuterTests {

   @ParameterizedTest
   @MethodSource("myInterfaceProvider")
   void test(MyInterface myInterface) {}

   static Stream<MyInterface> myInterfaceProvider() {
      return Stream.of(new ImplA(), new ImplB());
   }

   @Nested
   class InnerTests{

        @Test
        void nestedTest() {
            //how to access myInterface:MyInterface?
       }

   }

}
```

Comment: why not putting it member?

Comment: Sure, that would work. But how/where that member is set?

Comment: You can use @Parameter for Field injection, see more example here: https://github.com/junit-team/junit4/wiki/parameterized-tests if you want I can give a full example

Comment: @Parameter(s) is Junit4. I don't want to mix both libraries 4 and 5 (or is it recommended?). In 5, I could create a (constructor) ParameterResolver, but I don't know how to inject both objects "new ImplA()" and "new ImplB()"

Answer (score 1):

`InnerTests` won't be beneath the parameterized test in the test tree:

[image]

Thus, you cannot pass the argument of the test method to the nested test class.

Here's a way to define tests for interfaces in JUnit Jupiter:

```
interface MyInterfaceTests {

    MyInterface newInstance();

    @Test
    default void test() {
        MyInterface instance = newInstance();
        // test something
    }
}

class ImplATests implements MyInterfaceTests {
    @Override
    public MyInterface newInstance() {
        return new ImplA();
    }
}

class ImplBTests implements MyInterfaceTests {
    @Override
    public MyInterface newInstance() {
        return new ImplB();
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you can write it using `@TestFactory`:

```
@TestFactory
Stream<DynamicNode> test() {
   return Stream.of(new ImplA(), new ImplB())
       .map(instance -> dynamicContainer(instance.getClass().getSimpleName(), Stream.of(
           dynamicTest("test 1", () -> {
               // test something
           }),
           dynamicTest("test 2", () -> {
               // test something else
           })
       )));
}
```